# Create Singleton classes in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to  create singleton classes in kotlin which can be released in future.

Here is the code.

```
companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of repository opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AudioRepo? = null

        @Volatile
        private var counter: Int = 0

        @JvmStatic
        fun release() {
            synchronized(this) {
                // if counter is already 0 some sort of error has occurred
                if (counter == 0)
                    throw IllegalStateException("Counter variable is 0")
                counter--
                if (counter == 0) {
                    INSTANCE!!.destroy()
                    INSTANCE = null
                }
            }
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun get(context: Context): AudioRepo {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            synchronized(this) {
                counter++
                return INSTANCE ?: run {
                    val instance = AudioRepo(context.applicationContext as Application)
                    INSTANCE = instance
                    instance
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please check if this is good or I am doing something wronge.

The idea here is if an instance is obtaintained using get it needs to be released with release().
The counter determines when to clear the object.

**Update**
Since most of people seem to be confused why I need such approach. Let me explain.

The class AudioRepo needs to be Singleton in UI and Service.
Since I cant use any scope with hilt(I guess) to make it singleton so I used this approach.

I cant use kotlin object classs single I need to release the Couroutine Scope housed by audio repo and unregister Content Observer.

I can't use auto closable (as far as I Understand it) becuase I Use the instance in child composable of Jet Pack compose and In Service.

Comment: First, it looks like an overengineering. In most cases regular singleton should be enough. If you have good reasons for this reference counting then your solution seems fine, at least to me. If `get()`/`release()` is invoked frequently, but most of the time counter is above zero, then you can think about replacing synchronized block with solution based on CAS - it could be faster. But most probably you don't need this. Also, you can make `AudioRepo` implement `AutoCloseable` if you didn't already.

Comment: I read your update. People are confused, because it is unusual to have a component that is shared between other components and destroy and re-create it on demand. Usually, we just create it once and don't care that it exists when it is not used. This is why Hilt probably does not support this case. What is your concern regarding coroutine scope and content observer?

Answer (score 0):

### I think you should consider my solution:

```
open class Singleton<out T : Any>(creator: () -> T) {
    private var creator: (() -> T)? = creator
    @Volatile
    private var instance: T? = null
    fun getInstance(): T {
        val i = instance
        if (i != null)
            return i
        return synchronized(this) {
            val i2 = instance
            if (i2 != null)
                i2
            else {
                val created = creator!!()
                instance = created
                creator = null
                created
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--- Example

```
class ImageLoader private constructor(){
    companion object : Singleton<ImageLoader>(::ImageLoader)
}
```

Comment: It does a different thing - it does not destroy the object if it is no longer needed. And you actually re-invented [lazy()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/lazy.html).